# Change granularity of function plot to make plot look smooth

Tags: r, plot, granularity

Using the R `plot` function to plot another function, how can I increase the granularity so that the graph looks smooth?  I.e. something analogous to `seq(by=.001)`?

```
plot(sin, to=100)
```

[image: plot(sin, to=100) has jagged edges]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `plot(curve(sin, ...))`, and then set `n=` to your desired resolution.

```r
curve(sin, from=0, to=100)         # default, n=101
curve(sin, from=0, to=100, n=1001)
```

[image: curve with n=101]

[image: curve with n=1001]

Comment: I guess it's fair to ask the OP what the function was, as `?curve` suggests this approach for functions, though `curve(epxr,` still draws.